How should we polish the first paragraph of the tour page?
There was a meta.SE post about the site's name which drew my attention to this paragraph of the tour page:

Chinese Language and Usage is a question and answer site for experts, language enthusiasts, and people who have an interest in the Chinese language. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the Chinese language.

This snippet needs polishing.  I'll definitely want to stop using the site's old name.  While polishing, perhaps we should tweak "the Chinese language" to emphasize what languages count as Chinese.
Question: How should we polish the first paragraph of the tour page?


Chinese Language is a question and answer site for experts, language enthusiasts, and people who have an interest in the Chinese language family. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to questions about any variety of Chinese.

How's this?  I'm trying to keep this minimal:

"Chinese Language and Usage" -> "Chinese Language"

"...an interest in the Chinese language" -> "...an interest in the Chinese language family"

"...detailed answers to every question about the Chinese language" -> "...detailed answers to every question about some variety of Chinese" -> "...detailed answers to questions about any variety of Chinese." (Thanks dROOOze.)


I use the terms "family" and "variety" which are understandable by non-specialists, and are used on Wikipedia.  The meta post Why is the main site entitled "Chinese Language" rather than "Chinese Languages"? makes me want to avoid saying "the Chinese language".
Update: I went ahead and did it.  No-one seems to be objecting.  Feel free to bring it up again if you think of something better.

Looks excellent, I would just suggest at the end: "every question about some variety of Chinese" -> "questions about any variety of Chinese".

@dROOOze: thanks, that definitely an improvement!
